# Show / hide horizontal scrollbar depending on "wrap" option

Tags: vimrc, scrolling, wrapping

I'm trying to show / hide horizontal scrollbar conditionally, depending on `wrap` option:

- with `wrap` - show horizontal scrollbar
- with `nowrap` - hide

Here is what I tried, but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
set guioptions+=%{&wrap?'b':''}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want the horizontal scrollbar on `nowrap`.
You can handle this with a autocmd, like:

```
autocmd OptionSet wrap if &wrap|set guioptions-=b|else|set guioptions+=b|endif
```

If you change the option `wrap` *during runtime*, this will automatically switch on/off the horizontal scrollbar. The autocommand is not triggered on startup (sourcing `vimrc`), see `:help OptionSet`.

In your vimrc, you should define your initial settings like:

```
set nowrap
...
if &wrap
    set guioptions-=b
else
    set guioptions+=b
endif
```

This way, you just need to change `wrap` and `guioptions` will be changed as needed. Order is important here.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it doesn't work for me (does it work for you?). I have only two lines in vimrc currently: `set wrap` (`set nowrap`) and this one.

Comment: @james See update.

Comment: This should work in vimrc if you place the autocmd early enough, before the `set wrap`, in which case it'll be triggered.

Comment: @filbranden Doesn't work in `vimrc`. The docs say "Is not triggered on startup...".